# How do you start a Toolbox tool from ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I want to put a couple of toolbox Tools onto an AddIn toolbar.  I tried to reference the ProgIDs in the toolbar section of the Config.esriaddinx, but that didn't work (only saw blank spaces where the buttons should have been).  But since tools aren't actually buttons, it makes sense.

I only want to start the tool from an AddIn button--I want to trigger the double-click on the tool from toolbox. I don't want to actually provide the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing it a different way, but stumbled on the subtype in `<Item>` declaration in toolbar tag--and it exposes the subtype.

```
  <Toolbars>
    <Toolbar id="gse_id"
             caption="gse caption"
             showInitially="true">
      <Items>
        <Item refID="esriGeoprocessingUI.GPSystemToolCommand"  subtype="1" separator="true" />           
     </Items>
    </Toolbar>
  </Toolbars>
```

The alternative (which is the route I took) was to go ahead and create a new AddIn button, and then find the ICommandItem for `esriGeoprocessingUI.GPSystemToolCommand` and execute with something like this:

```
public static void Execute(this IDocument document, string name, int? subType)
{
    UID uid = new UID();
    uid.Value = name;

    if (subType.HasValue)
        uid.SubType = subType.Value;

    ICommandBars commandBars = document.CommandBars;

    ICommandItem item = commandBars.Find(uid) as ICommandItem;

    item.Execute();
}
```

In order to determine my subtypes, I manually added the Tools to a throw-away toolbar using the Customize window.  And then used [ArcGIS-GUID](http://faridcher.github.io/ArcGIS-GUID/) to dump the command information (specifically the subtype) as I clicked on them.